# void -[MKTileCache synchronize](MKTileCache*, objc_selector*) called while in background!

Tags: iphone

I'm working on an app which uses an MKMapView.
"Application does not run in background" is set to true in the app plist file.

When starting the app and then quiting the app using the home button, the app exits without any problems.

When I navigate to the second viewController I load an MKMapView in a UIScrollView.
When quiting the app from this screen, the app exits with status value:0 and the message:

```
void -[MKTileCache synchronize](MKTileCache*, objc_selector*) called while in background!
```

is displayed.

If I navigate to the second screen and then navigate back to the homescreen and exit the app with the homebutton, I have verified that the mapview is released, but I still get this message.

Can anybody help me out with this?
Would the app be rejected for this?

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar situation, using MKMapView, Application does not run in background set to true and I get the same error. I'm looking for ways to verify and/or solve it right now but my app has been reviewed and approved twice now with this setup so it does not appear to be a dealbreaker. Of course, YMMV

Comment: Good to know your app wasn't rejected for this.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I used MKMapView, but do not support backgrounding and I see this every time I close my app.  I've nilled the MapView and LocationManager, and also nilled both their delegates.  No effect on this error message.  I'm giving up.  No complaints from Apple.